# Функция возвращающая максимумы нескольких массивов

Tags: javascript

Помогите. Необходимо написать функцию getMaximum(arguments) где "arguments" это любое количество массивов. Возвращать функция должна максимумы этих массивов в строку через ";".

Comment: arguments это массив массивов или на его месте может быть любое количество аргументов, каждый из которых массив?

Comment: массив массивов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let g=(arr)=> arr.reduce((acc,el)=>acc+=Math.max(...el)+';','');

console.log(g([[1,6,3], [5,3,4]]));
```

---

```js
let g=arr=>arr.map(el=>Math.max(...el)).join(';');

console.log(g([[7,2,3], [9,3,4]]));
```

Comment: [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_function_calls)

Comment: В первом варианте, кстати, лишняя `;` :)

Comment: @Grundy  Я знаю)) Но никто не говорил, что в конце её не может быть ;-)

Comment: это подразумевалось _в строку через ";"_ то есть `;` между элементами, а не после них :)